# How to modify the parser rule return text in a one-liner action

Tags: antlr

Let's say I have the following grammar:

```
rule1 : sub1  sub2 sub3
    ;
```

Suppose I only want to return rule sub2's text and my target language is C. I tried:

```
rule1 : sub1  sub2 sub3
    {$text = $sub2.text;}
    ;
```

But it is not right. I think I saw some example somewhere I can simply change attribute, but google does not locate it.

Thanks for the help.

I am using ANTLR v3.4 and target language is C( the example in my mind does not use any C function though).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{$rule1.setText($sub2.text);}
```

I don't think assigning to $text will affect the return value of the rule.